# Connection between map function in Data.Map and fromList function

Tags: dictionary, haskell, map-function

I dont understand the signature of Map.map (map function in Data.Map) and that of Map.fromList. The function itself is in the signature. I am also not sure why Map.fromList is always called when i want to implement other functions such as Map.member or Map.filter or Map.size. Like why cant i just apply the function directly on the list but instead have to indirectly apply it through Map.fromList.

Last but not least... signature of fromList'. I notice that the called Map.Map function has a capital M instead of small m which is off (in reference to Map.map on second line) Why is this the case?

Thanks a lot

```
Map.fromList :: Ord k => [(k, a)] -> Map.Map k a
Map.map :: (a -> b) -> Map.Map k a -> Map.Map k b

fromList' :: (Ord a) => [(a,b)] -> Map.Map a b
fromList' = foldl (\acc (a,b) -> Map.insert a b acc) Map.empty
```

Comment: I don’t understand your question… `Data.Map` defines a `Map` *datatype*, which provides an efficient implementation of an immutable key/value dictionary. A list, on the other hand, is an ordinary singly linked list. They’re different data structures for different use cases. If you want to doing things like mapping or filtering on the list, use the usual `map` and `filter` functions from the `Prelude`, not the versions from `Data.Map`—those ones work on maps! (And the `map` function has little to do with the `Map` datastructure, they just use the same name for various reasons.)

Comment: A `Map` is an *associative array* (sometimes called a *dictionary*). It is *not* the `map` function on lists, etc.

Comment: Well, that _is_ actually a pretty unfortunate, confusing name clash. I can well understand how this would trip up beginners!

Comment: It may be helpful to note that Haskell is case sensitive: `foo` and `Foo` are different identifiers whose relationship, if any, is only by convention.

Answer (score 13):

Wow, looks like you are pretty confused.  It's understandable, since the word "map" means at least four different things!

1. The module `Data.Map` (you seem to be clear about this)
2. The *data type* `Map.Map k v` (in the `Data.Map` module), which is a finite map, aka "dictionary", aka "hash table" (but it doesn't use hashing)
3. The *function* `Map.map` (in the `Data.Map` module) which applies a function to every value in the `Map` (dictionary)
4. There is also the standard `map` function (in the `Prelude`) that works on lists, and has nothing to do with `Map`s (dictionaries).

Whew, what a mouthful!

---

Here's some explanation of the signatures:

```
Map.fromList :: (Ord k) => [(k, a)] -> Map.Map k a
```

`Map.Map k a` is a parameterized data type with two parameters, `k` and `a`.  If you are familiar with generics in the C++ family, this might be written `Map<K, A>`.

The `fromList` function takes a list of (key, value) pairs, `[(k, a)]`, and returns a dictionary.  The dictionary's keys have type `k`, and the values have type `a`.  `(Ord k)` means that the keys have to be orderable with respect to each other, because it stores the data structure as a sorted, balanced tree.

```
-- A dictionary from people's names to their age
ages :: Map.Map String Int
ages = Map.fromList [("Bill", 32), ("Carol", 71), ("Diddy", 13)]
```

---

```
Map.map :: (a -> b) -> Map.Map k a -> Map.Map k b
```

This takes a function from things of type `a` to things of type `b` as its first parameter.  As its second parameter it takes a dictionary from any key type `k` to things of type `a`, and it applies the function to every value in the dictionary, giving back a dictionary from the same key type to things of type `b`.

```
-- A dictionary from people's names to whether they are allowed to drink alcohol
canDrink :: Map.Map String Bool
canDrink = Map.map (\age -> age >= 21) ages
```

---

`fromList'` is just a custom implementation of `fromList`, implemented by repeated insertion.  It has the same signature as `fromList`, unsurprisingly (but the type variables are named differently -- this makes no difference).

Comment: Hi That really clear things up! Many thanks. Question about the last function. I notice that you use "age" as parameter to give a Bool value but in the "ages" function you defined the key as datatype (String and Int but not by names). Tho when I ran the code, it works. Can you explain this to me? Much appreciated

Comment: @Jung, hmm I can't quite understand what you are asking.  Here's a guess though: do you know the difference between `::` and `=` when defining a function?

Comment: Yes I do think so :: is to specify the type of a value whereas = is to set a value to sth. In `canDrink = Map.map (\age -> age >= 21) ages` you compare age of a person with 21. But you havent specified age in `ages`. In `ages` function you only specify the data type of the key and the value which are `String` and `Int`. So how does Haskell know that `age` is 32 or 71 or 13? also you didnt specify the datatype of `age` is Int

Comment: @Jung "In ages function you only specify the data type of the key and the value which are String and Int." No, that's what's specified in the type signature, but the actual definition tells us more than that. It tells us that the values in the map are `32`, `71` and `13` (and also what their corresponding keys are). Also note that `ages` is not a function. "So how does Haskell know that age is 32 or 71 or 13?" What do you mean by "the age"? All of those are the age of someone (32 is the age of Bill, 71 that of Carol etc.).

Comment: "also you didnt specify the datatype of age is Int" Haskell has type inference which makes the vast majority of type annotations optional. It is customary to give type signatures to global definitions (even though that's usually not necessary), but not usually to local ones. Haskell knows that the type of `age` is `Int` because the signature of `map` tells us that the function passed to `map` takes the map's value-type as an argument and we know that `ages`' value-type is `Int`.

Comment: @Jung `(\age -> age >= 21)` is a lambda: an inline anonymous function definition. It takes one argument (which we decided to call `age`, but it could be anything), and it returns whether that argument is greater or equal to 21. In other words, there is no significance to `age`, the definition could just as easily have been `canDrink = Map.map (\x -> x >= 21) ages`.

Comment: @DarthFennec thanks for the reference to lambda function! @sepp2k ahh so `a` in `Map.map (\age -> age >= 21) ages` is `Int` and `b` is `Bool`. So basically `canDrink` is the result of `Map.map :: (Int -> Bool) -> Map.Map String Int -> Map.Map String Bool` which is 'dictionary' with data type of key is `String` and that of value is `Bool`. is that correct?

Comment: @Jung yep, you got it!